# Firestore json data to listview with flutter

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

guys, I am developing a food order app I can read all data in my `Firestore` as a JSON but I need to use that data building a listview I just need separate those data **ITEM BY ITEM** do you know how can I do that at shortest way? thanks

LIKE THIS 
listview first tile
    ITEM NAME = iTEM1

IMGURL = android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg

QUANTITY = 2

PRICE = 10

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:resat/BurgerListView/data/food_,model.dart';

 class cart_page extends StatelessWidget {
 FoodItem foodItem;


    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
       body: new GestureDetector(
          child: Text('asd'),
         onTap: () async {
             var docs = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('cart')
          .document('LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd')
          .get()
          .then((DocumentReference) => DocumentReference.data);

      print(docs);
    },
  ),
);
 }
}
```

`
this is my firestore 
[image: this is my firestore]

and this is my printed docs which are JSON data printed from `Firestore`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Listview.Builder` in flutter? Check the [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-listview-and-scrollphysics-a-detailed-look-7f0912df2754) maybe it will be helpful for you. Also, You can map your Firestore response with a model using [JSON Serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) in the flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some nice tutorials about `Listview.builder` which should be used:

[Tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/flutter-listviews)

[Flutter.dev reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

[Nice tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdWhYERuv7g)

I think you should figure it out from this.

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
  body: Builder(builder: (context){
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('cart').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Center(
            child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading...'),
            );
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((
                  DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return  ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['asd']),

                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  })
```